# CoreData search with RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, search, core-data, restkit

I'm working on an app where I have two models, in a view controller I want to make a search and find instances from both models that matches the search keywords and list them in a tableview. I also use RestKit to store objects in core data. I later also want to update the search result with server results later after I first have made a local search.

My current - probably naive - attempt looks like this:

```
- (void)search
{

    if (self.searchField.text !=nil) {
        NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"post contains[cd] %@", self.searchField.text];
        self.posts = [[Post findAllWithPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];

        // reload the table view
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }    

    [self hideKeyboard];

}
```

This results in the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (post CONTAINS[cd] "t")'
```

The tableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    Post *post = [self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleLabel.text = post.title;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas on how a search like this should look would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at [RKGitHub](https://github.com/RestKit/RKGitHub) example project, which shows off the features of RKTableController class.

As for the error, I don't think it is related to your question.

Comment: The problems was mainly with my predicates, using a NSCompoundPredicate solved most of it. I also misunderstood how the predicates works. Anyway, thanks for your answer, the link looks cool.